# How to parse empty [] using spray.json

Tags: json, scala, spray-json

I have the following Json:

```
{
    "my_rule":[
      {
        "labelField": "abc",
        "nodeAttr":[]
      },
      {
        "labelField": "def",
        "nodeAttr":["name","surname"]
      }
    ]
}
```

I am parsing it in Scala using `spray.json`:

```
my_map = parsedJson.map(rule =>
  Map(
    "label" -> rule.labelField,
    "attr" -> rule.nodeAttr(???) // TODO
  )
)
```

The `attr` is of type `Seq[String]`.

I don't know how to resolve the case of empty `nodeAttr`? The goal is to have `attr` equal to `""` and `"name,surname"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_map = parsedJson.map(rule =>
  Map(
    "label" -> rule.labelField,
    "attr" -> (if(rule.nodeAttr.size == 0 ) "" else rule.nodeAttr.mkString(","))
  )
)
```

Comment: Do you mean `rule.nodeAttr.size` ?

Comment: Please also do `rule.nodeAttr.mkString(",")`.